# How to implement jacoco code coverage in Spock unit testing for generic 'Exception' catch block?

Tags: rest, api, junit, spock, jacoco

I have a springboot rest api which performs 'Select' operation in database based on 'studentId' which is of type 'String'.
Below I have simulated the scenario with a sample student example.

I have written 2 unit tests ( using spock and junit mockito) to validate the functionality. ( Unit test code I have not mentioned in this question hoping that it would not be required )

units tests --

1. Calling the api with a valid 'studentId' for which a record exists in database
   This unit test validates the functionality written in try {} block (else part )
2. Calling the api with a invalid student id. There is no record in the database for this student id.
   This unit test validates the functionality written in try {} block (if condition) and later goes in the catch(NoDataFoundException) block

I have also implemented jacoco to measure the code coverage. The problem is jacoco covers the entire code and marks it as green, except for catch(Exception) block. 
The reason is pretty obvious that I have not provided any unit test to cover catch(Exception) block.
The problem is I could not think of any scenario which can cause an 'Exception'. still I would like to keep the catch(Exception) in my code so as to catch any unpredictable exceptions

Some people may argue that I should not have catch(Exception) and they might be right with their reasoning, but its important, at least the nature of project I am working on, it really is.

Did some one come across such kind of situation? What you did to cover catch(Exception) in jacoco code coverage report. Any advice, pointers would be much appreciated.

Below is controller class-

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    StudentInfoRepository studentInfo; // StudentInfoRepository is Interface having method 'fetchStudentDetails'. This method is provided implementation in a class named 'StudentInfoImplementation'

    @RequestMapping(value = "/students/{studentId}", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getStudentInfo(@PathVariable("studentId") String studentId) throws Exception {

    Result<StudentModelClass> studentList = null;
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
    try {
        studentList = studentInfo.fetchStudentDetails(studentId);
        //if no records are returned for given studentId then throw custom 'NoDataFoundException'
        if (studentList.isExhausted()) {
            throw new NoDataFoundException("No record found for the requested studentId: " + studentid);

        //if records are returned for the given studentId then return 200 response and list of records
        } else {
            response = new ResponseEntity<Object>(studentList.all(), HttpStatus.OK);
            return response;
        }
    } 

    catch(NoDataFoundException ex){
        throw new NoDataFoundException(ex.getMessage());
    } 

    catch(Exception ex){
        throw new Exception(ex);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of Jacoco as stated in the [FAQ](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html)

> Source code lines with exceptions show no coverage. Why?
>
> JaCoCo determines code execution with so called probes. Probes are
>   inserted into the control flow at certain positions. Code is
>   considered as executed when a subsequent probe has been executed. In
>   case of exceptions such a sequence of instructions is aborted
>   somewhere in the middle and the corresponding line of source code is
>   not marked as covered.

Comment: Thanks Leonard for answer! Now it seems there is no other way than to live with the less code coverage. Anyways thanks for pointing out that it is a problem with jacoco, else i had to dig more to find out a working solution.

Comment: Yeah, I know it also bothers me, but that is the way they implemented it. @MaFiA could you accept the answer?